# Is it possible to use a function in a different module but use the variables where the fn() got imported?

Tags: python, function, scope, python-import

I'm working on some legacy code and i'm trying to refactor some of it.

With how JS scope works, functions look for variables inside the function but if it's not in the function it checks the outer scope to see if it's there and uses it. Instead when I import a function from a different module on python it is looking for variables from the imported file. I was wondering if there was a way to bind the function to the imported file so it looks inside there instead.

ex:

```
#functions.py
def callOutOfScope():
   x = y + 1
   return x
```

```
#main.py
from functions import *
y = 2
z = callOutOfScope() # it says y is not defined because it's looking for it in functions file
```

I was expecting to get 3 from z but I don't really know how python scoping works and how to do this with python.

I know I can pass y as an argument but it's a bit more complicated than that, for the exact reason why I want to bind the imported function to the current file. The same function is also being used in different files

Comment: did the other answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do what you are trying to do would be to pass `y` as a parameter

```py
def callOutOfScope(y):
   x = y + 1
   return x
```

then call it with

```py
y = 2
x = callOutOfScope(y)
```

Comment: Please read the whole question, I know I can do that. I appreciate the answer though.

Comment: if the variables are declared at the root of the module, then `import *` should import those too
this is pretty bad practice though, and you should not be doing that. Please give a good reason to use the module this way.

Comment: Bro I know its bad practice, I just got to this company but they pay me good. I don't want to refactor the whole thing tbh. The variables are not declared at the root of the module, again it's mentioned in the e? as well as it's being used in other files as well Ix'm fluent in JS but not that fluent in Python. Theres no good reason, they say it works so i'm trying to find simple ways to refactor without doing the whole thing. Thanks, Im not trying to be rude btw. There is a way to do it on JS but im looking for a way if possible on python by binding the function somehow to the current module

Comment: see my other answer. I tried this and that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem, and the way to solve this involves editing the out of scope module

`y` is somehow a variable of that module, so you need a way to edit the global variable `y` in that module

so you would have:

```py
# functions.py
def callOutOfScope():
    x = y + 1
    return x

def set_y(new_y):
    global y
    y = new_y
```

Then in the other module you can call:

```py
from functions import *
set_y(1)
x = callOutOfScope()
```